# Struggling with MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I want to create a trigger that inserts the total sum of all the products of an order into payments, but I'm facing syntax errors. Here's what I wrote so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_total BEFORE INSERT on payments 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

DECLARE id INT(10);

DECLARE temp INT(10);

SET id:=new.Order;

SELECT SUM(Price) into temp

FROM products , order_products

WHERE order_products.Order LIKE id AND products.Products_ID=order_products.Products;

SET new.Total:=temp;

END;
```

I can't figure out my syntax error, please help.

EDIT: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

Comment: Can you include what the syntax error is saying?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

Answer (score 1):

In multi-statement triggers, procedures, etc... you need to temporarily override the delimiter, so MySQL does not think the first `;` it runs across is ending the trigger/procedure/etc...

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER set_total BEFORE INSERT on payments 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

DECLARE id INT(10);
DECLARE temp INT(10);

SET id:=new.Order;

SELECT SUM(Price) into temp
FROM products , order_products
WHERE order_products.Order LIKE id AND products.Products_ID=order_products.Products;

SET new.Total:=temp;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Sidenote: This is generally considered a better form of the query you use to calculate the sum:

```
SELECT SUM(Price) into temp
FROM products
INNER JOIN order_products ON products.Products_ID=order_products.Products
WHERE order_products.Order = id;
```

Also: careful with declaring variable names that could be ambiguously interpreted as field names; if `products` and/or `order_products` have an `id` field, then that "where" condition could cause unexpected results; at best it would still make it unnecessarily difficult to read.

Comment: thank you so much , so the problem was the delimiter? Can you explain me why the trigger didn't work without the delimiter if it doesn't bother you

Comment: I posted originally without explanation; does the additional text I edited with answer that for you?

Comment: yes ,  again you have my thanks for the explanation you helped me a lot